# Call an REST API before closing window (React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, fetch

I am creating a React App which creates a user when the user access the app and deletes that user from the database when the user closes the browser or reloads. For backend I have used Mongodb and Nodejs.
I have tried using unload and beforeunload event listeners but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way you can do is to have a polling mechanism from the backend to check if the window is still open. Here are 2 solutions that I can think of:

1. Make a websocket connection from the window to server. If the socket is closed => window is closed (Firebase uses this method for its `onDisconnect`)
2. Use a `setInterval` to periodically send a ping (through REST API) to the backend. If the backend no longer receives ping, that means the window is closed.

Additionally, you can assign a random ID to each window. It will help to detect the case where users still open the window, but they lose connection.

Answer (score -1):

React Client executes "componentWillUnmount" before exit. ALWAYS.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

So call the server clean-up API there.

---

As Dan reminded me, this method is not reliable. The proper way to do this is to implement sessions on the node/express side with express-sessions, so once the user session expires, their entire user entry in the session storage is nuked.

Comment: `componentWillUnmount` is not guaranteed to run when the user closes their browser or tab, or navigates to a different site.

Comment: I think we're diving into server-side session territory now... as there is no "reliable" client-side solution that can be done, technically speaking, if you want to talk about timeouts, suspended tabs, and so on.